# jQuery events execute after the user stops scrolling (Pitcher)

Tags: jquery, html, events, scroll, jquery-waypoints

I have an issue with a few jQuery events on my page. I'm developing a website that should work only on iPad through a system called Pitcher. It's essentially a normal website but Pitcher pushes it to the device and saves it offline. I'm using [Waypoints.js](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/waypoint/) and when testing in the browser my events fire normally - as soon as the page reaches the markers that trigger the events, but in Pitcher they only start after the scrolling has finished.

As you may imagine, this causes a problem with a changing background - the user needs to stop scrolling to see the change.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('.overlay').waypoint(function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down'){
        $('#bg').removeClass('bg');
        $('#bg').addClass('bg2')
        $('.someclass').show();
    } else {
        $('#bg').removeClass('bg2');
        $('#bg').addClass('bg')
        $('.someclass').hide();
    }
}, {
    offset: -850
});
```

I simply need the events to start while the user is still scrolling. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a JSFiddle? Does this only happen on mobile? When browsing the example demo's of Waypoints the event fires while scrolling, not when I finish scrolling.

Comment: I can't reproduce it unfortunately, it seems to be very specific to Pitcher. They work as you scroll in a browser and on the iPad browser too. The problem is only within the Pitcher app.

Comment: I don't know Pitcher so this is just a wild guess, but check if Pitcher is binding any events to scroll. That may be interfering.

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks. I've also taken it up to the Pitcher support guys and see if they can help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 was the first version of iOS that will fire scroll events normally as a user scrolls. All versions of iOS before this would fire one event at the end of scrolling like you see with Pitcher.

**The thing is...** this new feature only applies to Mobile Safari. Applications using web views are given an inferior JS engine and still only fire scrolls once at the end.